# How do we maintain a driver's license

Tags: united-states, licensing, virginia, residency

We are planning to buy an RV to live & travel in. All our bills are digital, so we don't need a mailing address. It wouldn't make financial sense to keep a rental as we would never be there. My question is how do we maintain our drivers licenses and insurance?

Comment: What state are you drivers licenses and insurance in now?

Comment: Sorry... In Virginia, USA

Comment: You might want to check with some RV owner organizations - They would know this sort of thing, including handling mail, etc. My parents were (years ago) part of Escapees (https://escapees.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Once you are a Virginia resident, you remain a Virginia resident until you establish a residence in another state.

Both your driver's license and your license plate should therefore be renewed in Virginia until you make another state your home.

Comment: the address on your DL would be invalid if you no longer lived there.

Answer (score 0):

#### South Dakota

South Dakota seems to have [favorable laws to full-time RV'ers](https://www.nomadswithapurpose.com/south-dakota-residency-full-time-rv/).  Without an address, you would be classified as homeless.